# Axios adds Content-Dispositionand Content-Type to payload on PUT request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, request

I am using axios library (v 1.4.0) from React for sending files via PUT method to s3 bucket. All goes well, except axios adds to payload extra lines (like headers) and those become a part of a file itself. See example https://i.imgur.com/VGNdR3d.png

How can I avoid this behavior?

I have to use axios due to it's onUploadProgress callback that allows me to get a percentage of upload and create progress bar with animations.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (uploadUrls.length > 0) {
      files.map(file => {
        const fileUrl = uploadUrls.filter(f => f.fileName === file.name)[0].url;
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);

        axios
          .put(fileUrl, formData, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
            onUploadProgress: progress => {
              setUploadProgress(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                [file.name]: Math.round(
                  (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100
                ),
              }));
            },
          })
          .then(data => {
            setUploadProgress(prevState => ({
              ...prevState,
              [file.name]: 100,
            }));
            updateFileUploadStatus(file.name, importId, 'done');
          })
          .catch(error => {
            updateFileUploadStatus(
              file.name,
              importId,
              'error',
              error.response.data.error
            );
            setUploadError(error.response.data.error);
          });

        return null;
      });
    }
  }, [uploadUrls]);
```

UPD: If I send this file via Postman everything is fine, no additional lines inside file were added.

Comment: Did you try using axios like this ? _axios({method: 'put', url: https://example.com/request', data: your_payload, headers: { ... }})_

Comment: I've found similar issue, OP was sending request from another browser, but I don't know how to apply that fix to axios. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781909/webkitformboundary-included-in-file-payload-on-direct-upload-to-s3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I've switched to XHR and it works fine. Be aware, though, for chunked uploads this won't do.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (uploadUrls.length > 0) {
    files.map(file => {
      const fileUrl = uploadUrls.filter(f => f.fileName === file.name)[0].url;
      storeFileUploadInfo(file.name, fileUrl, importId);

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file);

      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('PUT', fileUrl, true);
      xhr.upload.onprogress = e => {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
          setUploadProgress(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [file.name]: Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100),
          }));
        }
      };

      const _send = xhr.send;
      xhr.send = function() {
        _send.call(xhr, file);
      };
      xhr.send(formData);

      return null;
    });
  }
}, [uploadUrls]);
```